# Is there an equivalent of an OnModal message in MFC?

Tags: winapi, mfc, modal-dialog

My MFC application has multiple top level (parented to the desktop) windows, any one of which can host an external application which can launch a modal dialog. Is there a way for one the other top level windows to get a notification when any of the others becomes modal?

My specific problem is that one of the my windows is hosting an embedded PDF viewer and when the user clicks print, only the window hosting the viewer is locked, not the others.

Comment: Windows do not become *modal*, they get deactivated. A window receives a [WM_ACTIVATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646274.aspx) message when it gets deactivated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a modal dialog is shown EnableWindow(FALSE) is called for the parent. It is deactivated now and will not accept any mouse input. Also it will not receive the keyboard focus.

When EnableWindow(FALSE) is called [WM_ENABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms632621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with wParam==FALSE is sent to the window.

When your parent receives this message you can call EnableWindow(FALSE) for all your other windows too. Recursion might be a problem here, but you can use a private window message or flags to prevent this.

Before the modal dialog closes EnableWndow(TRUE) is called again and WM_ENABLE with wParam==TRUE is sent again.

Comment: [Starting point for more information on enabling windows and modality](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/27/81155.aspx) A good chunk of The Old New Thing from 2003-2005 cover dialogs and modality in more depth.